# Do I leave an identifiable trace if I use a torrent client on different network connections?

Tags: bittorrent, privacy, vuze

I am using a usb-stick based operating system. So I use different computers and network connections. If I use Vuze for example, could a remote entity (eg a tracker) track my movements by seeing some sort of unique identification for my Vuze installation appear at different ip adresses?

If so, is there a way I could change id everytime I start the program to avoid this problem?

Comment: The purpose of a tracker is to track the torrent (peers and seeds), not any personally identifiable user info. As far as I know Vuze client does not transmit any personally identifiable info back to the tracker server (besides the ip address).

Comment: In any case, you leave a profile if you have a bunch of downloads going. If say a number of my downloads have tracker.openbittorrent.com as a tracker, the number of other people having the exact same set of files would be very slim, so that is identifiable. I didn't mention this in the question cause it is obvious. I know trackers are not "meant" for this, that does not mean that someone who could obtain their logs could not mean to trace a user.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. They can see where the traffic is coming from, but since USBs do not have any real unique identification possible in general (and it if did it would not get to the web anyway) there is no way for it to be tracked.

Comment: I'm not worried about the usb stick leaking, rather about vuze having a unique identifier, like with edonkey programs which work with a credit system.

Comment: They don't (padding).

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, a remote entity could track your position.
But not based on your torrent client - instead, some trackers are private (they give you points for being a good seeder) and they can track you. If you only use public trackers, however, then no.

There's another level of indirection here: dynamic IPs. if your IP is dynamic, then the answer goes back to *no*, since they barely know if you're in the city, and depending on the country, not even that is precise.

Comment: how does a private tracker recognize you? Does your client send an identifiable info to a private tracker that it does not send to a public tracker?

Comment: @ufotds No, it just tracks your IP. No personal info is shared by torrent clients, since BitTorrent was *meant* to be a private network from the beginning. An IP, however, is rarely of much use. (It tracks your IP because the tracker URL your client uses is customized, that is, the torrent you downloaded is customized to use a specific URL that, on the server, means you).

Comment: As a side note, the information a tracker can get from you is mostly: when your PC is downloading/seeding from its torrents, and from which city/state if your IP is dynamic (if it is static, maybe your approximate physical location).